# Arranging inputs with Shiny in R

Tags: r, user-interface, layout, shiny

I have these two checkbox groups, 'one' and 'two'....As you can see, they're stacked on top of each other, and they scroll endlessly down the page.

How can I put these checkbox groups next to each other instead of on top of each other?

```
   ui.r
 library(shiny)

    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

      # Application title
      headerPanel("Example"),


      sidebarPanel(
        checkboxGroupInput("one", "One:",letters[1:26]),
        checkboxGroupInput("two", "Two:",letters[1:26]),

      ),

      mainPanel(

      )
    ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello you can do like this, but `selectInput` with `multiple=TRUE` is maybe more adapted for what you want.

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Example"),

  sidebarPanel(
    div(class="row-fluid",
        div(class="span3",
            checkboxGroupInput("one", "One:",letters[1:26])),
        div(class="span3",
            checkboxGroupInput("two", "Two:",letters[1:26]))),

    selectInput("three", label="Three", choices=letters, multiple=TRUE)

  ),
  mainPanel()
))
```

Comment: This works great.  One more thing, though...I'm not really using single letters as button names, and the columns are too close together causing labels to overlap.  Is there a way to add offset to the DIV?

Comment: Got it!  span5 instead of span3 did the trick.  Thanks again.